# Could not Alter/Drop the trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, timeout, locking

I could not ALTER the trigger as its taking more then 80 min, and cannot delete/drop also , while trying to do this from Designer mode it shows erroe as

->`Drop Failed for trigger. "LOCK request timeout period exceeded."`
[image]
But the same trigger has been ALTER/DROP in other database containing same table.

- I have changed the `Table and Database Designers` transaction timeout
  after to 30000 sec as suggested by some of the Forms.
- And Uncheck
  `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`   inside
  TOOLS->OPTION->DESIGNER.
  After running Activity monitor
  [image]

Is my trigger not ALTERING/DROPPING Due to this ? Or some other reasons?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most probably there is another process with an open transaction on the table. 
To find what process has open transactions:

1. `DBCC OPENTRAN (`Database`)`
2. exec sp_who2
3. from SSMS right click on the server name, select `Activity Monitor`. If you run it while you are trying to alter the trigger, you can look in the `blocked by` column.

then you need to end the spid that has the open transaction or worst case to `kill spid`

Comment: DBCC OPENTRAN [BumHy]
Shows-Incorrect syntax near BumHy.

And i could not find Activity Monitor on right clicking on database name.

Comment: The transaction information is -

Transaction information for database 'BumHY'.

Replicated Transaction Information:
        Oldest distributed LSN     : (0:0:0)
        Oldest non-distributed LSN : (3383:7572:1)
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't find `Activity Monitor` when you right click on the `ServerName`? did you try `EXEC sp_who2`?

Comment: I am really sorry, i was clicking on database name, anyhow i have uploaded the activity screen in my updated answer.

Comment: expand `processes` bar to see details

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37495/discussion-between-luis-ll-and-teju-mb)

Comment: - In step 2, Use execute sp_who2 'active' can help you filter the result for actived spid
- Blocked By is blkBy column

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROC er_kilitlenmecoz as
declare @max_count int, @count int, @sqlstring varchar(100)
declare @spid_table table (spid int NOT NULL)

INSERT @spid_table
select spid
from master.dbo.sysprocesses
where spid in (select blocked from master.dbo.sysprocesses where blocked <> 0) and blocked = 0

select @max_count = MAX(spid) FROM @spid_table
select top 1 @count = spid from @spid_table

while @count <= @max_count
begin
select @sqlstring = 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @count)
exec(@sqlstring)
print @sqlstring

IF @count = @max_count
begin
break
end
ELSE
BEGIN
select top 1 @count = spid FROM @spid_table where spid > @count
end
end
```

--- RUN SCRİPT--DİSABLE TRİGGER